# Multiple Directories of Images in JavaScript using an if loop

Tags: javascript, image, file, directory

I have an array of pictures that are from mulitple sub-folders. I am trying to do the `if` loop to see if the files from the array are located in the following folders without writting each file and it's full local path.

```js
let i = 0;
let imageArray = [];
let time = 2000;
    
imageArray = [
        "winhistory.jpg",
        "winsymbol.png",
        "10.jpg",
        "win08diskprop.jpg",
        "win98install.jpg",
        "Windows-logo.jpg"
];
const imageDir = imageArray => {
        if ((document.slide.src = "../images/windowspics/")) {
            "../images/windowspics/" + imageArray[i];
        } else if ((document.slide.src = "../images/coins/")) {
            "../images/coins/" + imageArray[i];
        } else if ((document.slide.src = "../images/codelang/")) {
            "../images/codelang/" + imageArray[i];
        }
        return imageArray;
};
const changeImg = () => {
        if (i < imageArray.length - 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    
        window.onload = changeImg;
};
```

Comment: `if` is not a loop. What do you want to do, if the condition is passed? Currently you're evaluating an expression, and throwing the resulted value away.

Comment: i want it to access the give subfolders, i have images that are in the coins folder, the windowspics and the codelang folder

Comment: const imageDir = imageArray => {
    for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((document.slide.src = "../images/windowspics/")) {
            console.log("");
        } else if ((document.slide.src = "../images/coins/" + imageArray[i])) {} else {
            document.slide.src = "../images/codelang/" + imageArray[i];
        }
    }

Comment: i am looping though directories of where these images can be located.